# How to detect that a firewall has blocked Internet access to some app?

Tags: android, firewall

This app must not work without active Internet connection. But, checking Internet connection via `ConnectivityManager` and `NetworkInfo` does not work if firewall apps like `DroidWall` have denied access to Internet (firewall rule).

How can I detect that some firewall app has blocked Internet access to my app?

For example, if I start Google Play Store app, it clearly states "No Internet connection". If I start my app, it hangs (trying to download content) and then crashes with an error.

**EDIT**

This is error caught by Logcat.

```
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    at com.app.android.MainActivity$ParserAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:345)
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    at com.app.android.MainActivity$ParserAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:367)
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-05 12:44:51.417: E/AndroidRuntime(18922):    ... 5 more
```

As you see, the mechanism which detects whether Internet connection (wifi or mobile data) exists or not failed as the app was started and the parser started downloading remote content.

I need to implement additional feature which will allow Internet connection mechanism to check if some app is blocked by some firewall rule (like Play Store app does).

Comment: Can you please post the error? Full exception.

Comment: try to do what I suggested below. And add the code that is throwing the NullPointerException - at mainactivity.java lines 345->367. Most likely the firewall is causing your connection variable to become null and you are not testing for this. Simply checking what it has returned will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is crashing then it's throwing an exception you are not catching.

Try to surround your connection code with `try/catch and pop a toast notification` that there is **no internet connection available** in the catch. Also, post the exception from the debugging tools? I'm curious what exception you are getting since you haven't posted any code...

Comment: Thanks but I know this approach :). I was hooping there is a way to detect that some firewall app is blocking access.

Comment: There is. Check the iptables of the underlying OS. If the IP of the website you are trying to reach is blocked by a rule there, it was added by a firewall application - that uses iptables to restrict access of course. Unfortunately, it's not an easy task since the code would run only on rooted phones and it's possible you will run into compatibility issues with different modded OS. Simply check weather the connection is null to find restricted internet, host not found exceptions for your part of the "fault" (bad ip, bad hostname in code) or check network connection by the means you already use

Comment: Google Playstore on default Android OS won't run as root and it doesn't detect firewalls, it simply handles exceptions < a wild guess.

Comment: I think you may be right. I forgot about rooted and unrooted phones. I will leave this unmarked as a reply for a day or two. If someone does not suggest a better solution, I will mark yours as the answer. Thanks